# How to a read CSV file that contains Arabic lines using Python

Tags: python, csv

This is the code and the output is as `\xef\xbb\xbf\`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs
import csv
import sys  


with open(u'csv.csv', 'r') as csvfile:                                                     
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Comment: How is the file encoded? `with codes.open(u'csv.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:` may be what you want, but which encoding you choose depends on how the file was saved.

Comment: the file encoded asa utf-8 bom , this also dosnt work and i get the error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-5: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I think you can use `utf-8-sig` for the encoding. That decodes the BOM you posted.

Comment: Also, remove the `'r'`. The default `'rb'` is what you need for decoding.

Comment: The same error 

Comment: You haven't mentioned what the error is or given a sample that produces that error.

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-4: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python 2 `csv` module doesn't handle unicode encodings well. The best solution is to start using python 3 which has integrated unicode and is well-suited for multi-language programming. If you need to stick with python 2, the `unicodecsv` module (`pip install unicodecsv`) is a drop-in replacement for `csv` that handles non-ascii files.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys

try:
    import unicodecsv as csv
except ImportError:
    sys.stderr.write(
        "`sudo pip install unicodecsv` for unicode csv support\n")
    exit(1)

with open(u'testfile.csv', "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, encoding="utf-8-sig")
    for row in reader:
        print u", ". join(row)
```